# So... when is this beta going to be deleted?

Tags: discussion, beta

At 0.2 questions a day, I think it's clear that this beta is a failure.

I suggest the plug be pulled and the beta deleted.

Comment: Looking at your question history, I'm [starting to think](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RtDXD-weXk) you have a personal vendetta against our site :P... which is fine (and mind you, I haven't downvoted any of your questions), but please come up with some new arguments if you're gonna ask [this question](http://meta.beer.stackexchange.com/questions/79/should-we-consider-closing-this-beta) a third time ;-)

Comment: @AndrewCheong No. Look at my post history. I was active right in the private beta. I just think this beta has failed.

Answer (score 6):

Beer currently gets more visits per day than 37 other SE sites, including one that has graduated. When the questions and answers are of good quality, the site helps people without them even having to ask. And when they do ask, they get an answer pretty quickly.

[Stack Exchange recently announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/259867):

> If there's enough moderation for a public beta site to consistently remain free of spam, for flags to be cleared, and for our Be Nice policy to be upheld, your site will remain open.

I don't know about flags, but there isn't any visible spam or nastiness around at the moment, so at least that part is taken care of.